# No PHP parser results?

Tags: support, search

I was trying to search SO for a PHP parser and got blank results:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+parser.

No error message, just a big blank area. However, the bottom of the page showed 17 pages of results. Clicking on them show blank pages as well.  Wazzup?

Comment: The same query works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably ignored the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag and selected the *Hide Ignored Tags* option in your profile.

Comment: Got to like the client side filtering of questions.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Jeff, any chance of not hiding questions one specifically searches for?